# Mysql syntax error on line 1

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I write a query when doing a tutorial Agile web application development with yii. I was trying to alter a table with this query and got this error in phpmyadin

```
ALTER TABLE 'tbl_issue' ADD CONSTRAINT 'FK_issue_project' FOREIGN KEY
('project_id') REFERENCES 'tbl_project' ('id') ON DELETE CASCADE ON
UPDATE RESTRICT

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
> near ''tbl_issue' ADD CONSTRAINT 'FK_issue_project' FOREIGN KEY
> ('project_id') REFERE' at line 1
```

Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem may be that you're using single quotes instead of backticks as enclosing characters for table, field and index names.

Try: `` ALTER TABLE `myTable` ADD CONSTRAINT `myConstraint`... ``

(in case the posted code is actually what you used for your statement executed through phpMyAdmin).

Comment: Thanks a lot backticks does the job :)

Comment: Yeah, a bit irritating sometimes. Remember that string values referring to data are escaped with single quotes (`...where project_name = 'Cool Project')`.

Answer (score 0):

SQL doesnt require any single quote tags when specifying the name of the table.
This is also the case at insert and update create etc. remove the quotes and it should be fixed